# Extracting a chunk of data from a Http response returned as HTML document

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 4 (Angular) for a project and I want to ask if there is a way to extract a chunk of data from a HTTP response returned as a HTML document. The chuck of data that I want to extract from is wrapped in a pair of `<script></script>` tag.

I am considering regex method but is there any other way to do it more efficiently? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is using [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).

So you can do something like this.

```
let extractedData = data.split("<script>")[1].split("</script>")[0];
```

Comment: Hey, your solution worked pretty well for my problem. Thanks a lot!